# Scala - How to convert Map[Int,List[List[IntVar]]] to

Tags: scala, data-structures, flatmap, jacop

I am new in Scala programming and the flatmap function gives me headache.

Before you ask me to search, I made some research on Stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scala+map+to+list but I didn't find something to solve easily my problem.

Here is my problem :

For a scala programming project with Jacop (http://jacopguide.osolpro.com/guideJaCoP.html)  ,

I need to convert this kind of map

```
Map[Int,List[List[IntVar]]]
```

to :

```
List[T] 
// In my case , only a List[IntVar]
```

I know I should use several times flatMap but I wonder how correctly use that in my case.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should supply a expected input/output.

Comment: Do you want every `IntVar` in the values of the map to be in the output list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every `IntVar` from the values of the map, you could to this:

```
 map.values.flatten.flatten.toList
```

The call to `values` returns an `Iterable` containing all the values of the map. In this case, it returns an object of type `Iterable[List[List[IntVar]]]`. The first `flatten`-call on this object flattens it to an `Iterable[List[IntVar]]`. The second `flatten`-call flattens this object further to an `Iterable[IntVar]`. Finally, the `toList` method converts it to a `List[IntVar]`.

Comment: Thanks you with your explaned solution :)